# Get-ChildItem inconsistent behavior, inserting a space when using variable in path

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm attempting to read a list of computer names from a file and scan each for DLL files in a certain set of directories. Basically, I want it to scan every user's personal directory on the PC and look for any DLL files in the ..\AppData\Roaming\ directory.

This is not elegant by any means, but I'm new to PowerShell:

```
#runs DSQuery to get a list of machine names and export to a text file
c:\temp\get_pc_list.bat

$pcList = Get-Content c:\temp\pc_list.txt

#Removes a blank space at the end of each item in the text file
$pcList | foreach {$_.TrimEnd()} | Set-Content c:\temp\pc_list.txt

del C:\temp\file_check.txt

foreach ($computer in $pcList)
    {
        Get-ChildItem \\$computer\c$\users\*\AppData\Roaming\*.dll -recurse | Out-File -encoding unicode $("C:\temp\file_check.txt") -append -noclobber
    }
```

When I run it, I get a message that "an object at the specified path \PC101 \c$\users does not exist." It appears that it's adding a space after "PC101", which is the first item in my list. I've checked the file there are no extra spaces at the end of each line.

I've tried enclosing the path in double quotes, but the result is the same. Am I missing something or is it not possible to use a variable in the path?

Comment: Could you post the output of `[Regex]::Escape($computer)` in the `foreach` loop?

Comment: tried `Get-ChildItem \\$computer.trim()\c$\users\*\AppData\Roaming\*.dll` allready?

Comment: Myguess is DSQ上ry is returning some names with a space before the line return character (what splits the PC names). Use either trim, or ADComputer / QADComputer to work directly with PowerShell objects from AD would help...

Comment: @briantist : `PC101
PC102
PC103
PC104`

Comment: @Paul I tried that. Got an error. `An expression was expected after '('.`

Comment: well if $computer contains multiple servers you have to restructure your list so that you have only 1 value per line. then your code might work

Comment: and now that i look at it more closely, the line where you remove the spaces just saves that to the list. your `$pclist` variable has not changed. either do a `get-content` again or trim the actual array values

Comment: Running `Get-Content` again appears to be working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use AD-GetComputer to pull all the PC names into a variable?

You can also use export-csv is that would work better for you:

```
$Computers= Get-ADComputer  -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=accounting,dc=domain,dc=com" -Properties * |     
Select  -ExpandProperty name 

foreach ($computer in $Computers)
    {

    Get-ChildItem \\$computer\c$\users\*\AppData\Roaming\*.dll -recurse | Export-Csv    
    C:\temp\file_check -append -noclobber
     }
```

To return only the names of the DLLs you can change the Get-ChildItem line to:

```
     Get-ChildItem \\$computer\c$\users\*\AppData\Roaming\*.dll -recurse | Select-Object Name | Export-Csv    
     C:\temp\file_check -append -noclobber
```

Comment: I think that is ultimately what I'll have to do. I'm coming into an environment without ADWS installed, so I think I'll push for that. Thank you for the suggestion.